Aeschylus quote about wind, sea, skies and sun rays
I have this quote from Aeschylus that I wrote down a while ago, in French (I read Aeschylus oeuvre in French). I would like to know if anyone knows the exact English formulation of the quote, I mean how it is phrased in your English edition (if you know it by heart, well it's even better!).
Here it goes:

May all the winds that blow on the earth, from the seas or the skies, come, through the rays of an adequate sun, and blow on this land!

Many thanks in advance.

This is from a speech by Athena in Eumenides, lines 904–906. Here’s a selection of English translations.

And that, too, both from earth, and ocean’s spray,
And out of heaven; and that the breezy winds,
In sunshine blowing, sweep upon the land
E. H. Plumptre (1868). The Tragedies of Aeschylos, volume 1, page 204. London: Strahan.


                        chants from breast of earth,
From wave, from sky; and let the wild winds’ breath
Pass with soft sunlight o’er the lap of land
E. D. A. Morshead (1881). The House of Atreus, pages 176–177. London: C. Kegan Paul.


From the sea’s briny dew, and from the sky
Bring blessings; the benignly-breathing gales
On summer wings be wafted to this land
John Stuart Blackie (1906). The Lyrical Dramas of Aeschylus, page 169. London: J.M. Dent.


I implore blessings from the earth and from the waters of the deep and from the heavens; and that the breathing gales may pass o’er the land in radiant sunshine
Herbert Weir Smyth (1922). Aesychlus, volume 2, page 359. London: Heinemann.

